# find x in coordinates given the angle

Tags: analytic-geometry

**This is the problem:**

if the angle from the line through $(-4,2)$and $(3,-4)$ to the line through $(-4,2) (x,3)$ is arctan 37/29 find the value of $x$?

**Should i use this formula:**

$$\tan \theta= \frac{m_2-m_1}{1+(m_1)(m_2)} $$

i already try it. but it didn't give the right answer

Comment: @lsp: if you change “m1” to “$m_1$”, then do it **everywhere.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

$$|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1 \cdot m_2}|$$
$m_1 = \frac{-6}{7}$ and $m_2 = \frac{1}{x+4}$.